# Cannot set custom resolution in Lubuntu 17.10 VM

Tags: lubuntu, virtualization, display-resolution

I tried following the steps here: [Set a specific screen resolution with xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95977/set-a-specific-screen-resolution-with-xrandr)
..but I do not have the `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/`folder. Instead I have `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu` which *does* contain an autostart file, but after editing it and rebooting there was no change.

Here is another SE post that *does* reference the `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu` but the user there also could not get a custom resolution set: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130976/lubuntu-display-resolution-virtualbox

Here's what I'm trying in the text of /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
`xrandr --auto --primary --mode --1920x1080`

I'm running Lubuntu 17.10 in VMware Workstation.

Comment: are you running a wayland session? xrandr is a command for X11/Xorg

Comment: Thanks,@ravery. I'm running whatever is the default for Lubuntu 17. Let me see if I can figure out how to check...

Comment: It must be X11: `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11`

Comment: Do you have file `~/.xprofile` on Lubuntu?